# Stop Thread onPause

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to stop a Thread when the User leaves the Activity. It sounds so simple but no function, which i tried, works.

I start the Activity with the Code

```
lovi = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), listoverview.class);
lovi.putExtra("reloadAll", true);
startActivity(lovi);
```

In the onCreate of the listoverview i start the Thread with the Code

```
rlMF.start();
```

And rlMF looks like this:

```
public Thread rlMF = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        reloadMissingFiles();
    }
});
```

I tried in the onPause to use rlMF.stop(), .interrupt(), .suspend. Nothing stops it.

Comment: you have to use flag for this purpose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add some flag to  to stop it. Stopping thread by other means might have dire consequences, like resource leaks.

For example:

```
volatile boolean activityStopped = false;
```

When creating runnable:

```
public Thread rlMF = new Thread(new Runnable() { 

    public void run() {
        while (!activityStopped) {
        // reloadMissingFiles() should check the flag in reality
            reloadMissingFiles(); 
        }
    }
});
```

In onPause():

```
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    activityStopped = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Android Handler

```
Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        // do stuff
        handler.post(this);
    }
};

handler.post(r);
```

In the onPause:

```
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    handler.removeCallbacks();
}
```

Comment: My Function `reloadMissingFiles();` runs only once (but for a long time)... So i don't know how i could use your code...

Comment: Removing callbacks would not prevent already running code from completing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Thread` try and use an `AsyncTask`, this way you can call the `cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)` method of the `AsyncTask`. You should also keep in mind to catch the `InteruptedException` that may be thrown if you use `cancel(true)`.

Here's [a usefull tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html) about `Threads`, `Handlers` and `AsyncTask` that may help you.